# How to use binary search algorithm to find maximum value of ((sum of any continuous subarray) % m)?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Given an array of size N and an element M, we need to find the maximum value for (sum of any continuous subarray) % M using binary search algorithm?

Read complete problem statement here : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximize-sum

For example: 
If Array A = {3, 3, 9, 9, 5} and M = 7, then all possible continuos subarrays are {3}, {3}, {9}, {9}, {5}, {3, 3}, {3,9}, ........, {3, 9, 9, 5}, then answer will be 6 which is obtained from subarray {3, 3}.

An Algorithm can greatly help.

Comment: In Hackerrank you can click on the editorial button to view the answer

Comment: i can't understand the editorial solution, they are using sets instead of binary search i don't know why.

Comment: If it is a continuous sub-array with no mandatory order, why would you use binary search?

Comment: The question was under the binary search category, that's why i am asking